# How to get commits from another user in git and apply on top of mine?

Tags: git, github

I have 2 users in git working from a common repository but then making separate changes in their own local machine.

User 1 : --- Commit 1 --> Commit 2 --> Commit 3

User 2 : --- Commit 1a ---> Commit 2b --> Commit 3b

If I am user 2, How do I apply all of User 1's commits on top of my commits and bring my copy up to date ?

Answer (score 0):

Get User 1 to squash their commits into a single commit, and then save them to a file:

```
$ git diff-tree <aggregated-commit-id> -p --pretty > user1Commits.txt
```

Then you can take that file and use

```
$ git apply user1Commits.txt
```

To squash commits into a single commit, use

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
784a93064fefc74a7c4c53f96a578580cbdc398d Commit 3
96e67762fb245ec5fbb5ac5b642902b162d2665f Commit 2
949d3d7f9c40e74e2e68295b0b063ed21ae6cb2b Commit 1
```

Then run `git rebase --interactive HEAD~3` and you will get

```
pick 949d3d7 Commit 3
pick 96e6776 Commit 2
pick 784a930 Commit 1

# Rebase 84f9c68..784a930 onto 84f9c68
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Change the second two picks to squashes:

```
pick 949d3d7 c3
s 96e6776 c2
s 784a930 c1
```

and then save and quit twice.  Running `git log` again will show you the ID of your newly created aggregate commit.

Comment: Any way to do this without squashing?  I'd love to do this while keeping the original commit history.